# How to map dynamic properties in model class (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, oop, objectmapper

I am new to IOS Development, i came across a really interesting situation, i have this json response coming server side

```
{ 
  "caps": {
    "first_key": "34w34",
    "first_char": "34w45",
    "first_oddo": "34w34"
          ....  : .....
          ....  : .....
  }
}
```

My issue this that keys inside "caps" object can be dynamic (like what if one more value is added). I am using ObjectMapper to mapper to map values from response to model class. I have this model class

```
class User: Mappable {
    var first_key: String?
    var first_char: String?
    var first_oddo: String?
    required init?(map: Map) {
    }
    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        first_key   <- map["first_key"]
        first_char   <- map["first_char"]
        first_oddo    <- map["first_oddo"]

    }
}
```

Now as i dont know how to populate my model if values in json response are changed (because that are dynamic). I hope i have explained it well. I think i dont want hard coded values inside model?

Comment: You can use SwifyJSONAccelerator for mapping Json in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the `Codable` protocol introduced with Swift 4.

If the keys of your JSON are **dynamic** then you need a `Dictionary`.

### JSON

Given this JSON

```
let data = """
{
"caps": {
    "first_key": "34w34",
    "first_char": "34w45",
    "first_oddo": "34w34"
}
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

### The Response Model

You can define a struct like this

```
struct Response:Codable {
    let caps: [String:String]
}
```

### Decoding

Now you can decode your JSON

```
if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
    print(response.caps)
}
```

### Output

```
["first_key": "34w34", "first_oddo": "34w34", "first_char": "34w45"]
```